# Image not coming from servlet when called from jsp

Tags: image, oracle, jsp, servlets

I am trying to fetch image from oracle database.
Flow is : JSP (to read photo_id) -> JSP -> which internally calls Servlet from src attribute of HTML image tag.

ImageGetter.jsp (Asking for photo id)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>your Pic</title>
</head>
<body>

      <form id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="getPhoto.jsp" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Photo Id :</td>
                    <td><input  type="text"  name="id"/></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <p/>
            <input type="submit" value="fetch Photo"/>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

getPhoto.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Your photo</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String p_id=request.getParameter("id");%>


<table>
    <tr><td><%=p_id%></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="/getPic?photoid=<%=p_id%>" /></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

getPic in src attribute of img tag is servlet.

getPic.java

```
package com.kp.imagehandler;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.kp.imagehandler.Image;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class getPic
 */
public class getPic extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public getPic() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String imageId = request.getParameter("photoid");
        System.out.println(imageId);
        InputStream photoStream = (new Image()).getImageStream(imageId);


        BufferedInputStream input = null;
          BufferedOutputStream output = null;

          try {

              // Open streams
              input = new BufferedInputStream(photoStream, 200000);
              output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),
                      200000);

              // Write file contents to response.
              byte[] buffer = new byte[200000];
              int length;
              while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                  output.write(buffer, 0, length);
              }

              } finally {
                  output.close();
                  input.close();
              }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Image.java:

```
package com.kp.imagehandler;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Image {

    // Init ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    public InputStream getImageStream(String pid)
    {
        InputStream IS=null;
        try {

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.75.122.69:1521:devdb",
                "s3", "s3");
          Statement stmt = connection.createStatement ();

            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT photo FROM photo_holder where id="+pid);

            while(rset.next())
            {
                IS=rset.getBinaryStream("photo");

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return IS;

    }

    // Implement default getters and setters here.

}
```

web.xml :

```
  <servlet>
    <description>getPic</description>
    <display-name>getPic</display-name>
    <servlet-name>getPic</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.kp.imagehandler.getPic</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>getPic</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getPic</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Table definition:

```
create table PHOTO_HOLDER
(
  ID    NUMBER(5) not null,
  TITLE VARCHAR2(50),
  PHOTO BLOB
)
```

but after hitting fetch photo I am just getting photo id but not image.
Here I am not sure whether servlet is getting fired or not.

please help.thanks in advance.

Comment: _I am not sure whether servlet is getting fired or not._  . Try **debugging** your application to find it out

Comment: I agree Krish. I kept sysouts in servlets but not getting in eclipse console. so is it right way to call servlets from src attribute?

Comment: NO i wont agree with the way you are passing as query string as the `url` will be visible in the browser . use post instead

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with the URL formed for the image.

Please validate it again by simply looking at the **source code of the generated JSP** in the browser.

---

Just debug your code or use logging to investigate the issue.

Try it again after appending **context path** before the Servlet/JSP path as shown below:

```
<form id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/getPhoto.jsp" method="get">

<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/getPic?photoid=<%=p_id%>" />
```

Comment: Try it again after removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the `from` and making it `post` instead of `get`.

Comment: hi all, I debugged it and worked. Also, I added post instead of get so that id is not visible in url. So here popped up in mind, some portal suggested with get but with encrypted id values in url like md5. so how does it makes difference with post and which is better.

Comment: Please search on Google.